# If $T$ is the torsion subgroup of $H^n(M;R)$, then is $H^n(M;R)/T \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(H_n(M;R), R)$ an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $R$ be an abelian group and $M$ a topological space and let $h : H^n(M; R) \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(H_n(M;R), R)$ be the map that occurs in the universal coefficients theorem. If I let $T$ denote the torsion subgroup of $H^n(M;R)$, then is $H^n(M;R)/T \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(H_n(M;R), R)$ an isomorphism?

In other words, if I mod out torsion from $H^n(M;R)$ do I then get an isomorphism? This appears in the slightly different context of Poincaire Duality in Proposition 3.38 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book. I tried to prove this but didn't get far.

I know that we have the following exact sequence from the universal coefficients theorem
$$0 \to \operatorname{Ext}^1_R(H_{i-1}(M;R), R) \to H^n(M;R) \xrightarrow{h} \operatorname{Hom}_R(H_n(M;R), R) \to 0$$
and if we had $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(H_{i-1}(M;R), R)  = T$, then by exactness we'd be done, but I don't see any reason why this should be the case.

Moreover, I don't see why $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(H_{i-1}(M;R), R)$ contains any elements of finite order. If I added the further assumption that $R$ is finitely generated and instead considered $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(R; H_{i-1}(M;R))$, then by properties of Ext and the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups I can conclude that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(R; H_{i-1}(M;R))$  would contain *some* elements of finite order, but again I don't see why it would contain *only* elements of finite order. In any case we don't have that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(H_{i-1}(M;R), R) = \operatorname{Ext}^1_R(R; H_{i-1}(M;R))$ in general.

**Edit:** If there are counterexamples to the general case above, then you can take my question in the restricted case where $M$ is a closed orientable manifold.

Comment: Take $\mathbb R P^2$ and $R = \mathbb Z_2$

Comment: What do you mean by $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R$ if $R$ is an abelian group (as opposed to a ring)?